# How to find where ksh setup aliases?

Tags: ksh, alias

Where ksh can load aliases from?

- Checked /etc/profile, ~/.profile - nothing
- There is no ~/.kshrc.
- Tried:
  `$ grep -r 'alias BADALIAS' /etc` - also nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it...

The /etc/profile has a call to another script buried in conditions:

```
test -d $SITE -a -d $SITE/$VER -a -e $SITE/$VER/site_config && . $SITE/$VER/site_config
```

which in turn opens a text file with key=value pairs and makes aliases from this list. And that list has a bad pair...

Our admins are such strange people...